# Using share(): post last value to new subscribers

Tags: android, rx-java2

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    compositeDisposable.clear();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Flowable<MyData> distanceFlowable = myDataProcessor.hide().onBackpressureLatest()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .share();

    compositeDisposable.add(distanceFlowable)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(data -> {Log.w("observer 1", data.value)});

    compositeDisposable.add(distanceFlowable)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(data -> {Log.w("observer 2", data.value)});
}
```

The code works well when distanceFlowable gets new changes continuously. However in a scenario when there's only one post on the distanceFlowable only *observer 1* gets notified.

**It behaves like this:**

1. post on distanceFlowable
2. observer 1 subscribes
3. logcat prints "observer 1: 133"
4. observer 2 subscribes

**I would want it to behave like:**

1. post on distanceFlowable
2. observer 1 subscribes
3. logcat prints "observer 1: 133"
4. observer 2 subscribes
5. logcat prints "observer 2: 133"

I tried using `ConnectedFlowable` instead with `publish()` and then `connect()` to the flowable after both *observer 1* and *observer 2* are subscribed. But then it still posts on flowable even after the `compositeDisposable` is cleared and there is no one listening.

What is the preferred way to solve this?

Comment: What about .replay(1).refCount() ?

Comment: I read about that as well, but I couldn't get that to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed that `flowable.connect()` returns a `Disposable` that I could add to my `compositeDisposable`, that way it ends up being cleared in onPause.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.compose(ReplayingShare.instance());` from 
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare

That should work.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I needed. I would think they provided that by default.